# CSS BEM syntax without element class name

Tags: css, bem

I have to create a primary heading component, below is my markup along with CSS classes. I'm following BEM naming convention for class name.

I have `h1` element consists of two spans. One `span` for main heading text, and second `span` for sub heading text. The main and sub are variations of my heading.

I have not specified the Element class (Which could be `heading-primary__text` ) and i have directly attached modifier classes to `span` elements.

```
<h1 class="heading-primary">
  <span class="heading-primary--main">Video Background Option</span>
  <span class="heading-primary--sub">One Page Parallax</span>
</h1>
```

Is that a right way to follow BEM methodology without specifying Elements classes & attaching Block's modifiers classes to Elements(`span`)? Because i don't need elements classes.

Is there any alternate?

Answer (score 2):

While this is subjective, and as per the convinience of the project . i'd recommend doing something like this- as you already have a `header-primary_text` element class

```
    <h1 class="heading-primary">
      <span class="heading-primary_text">Video Background Option</span>
       <!--create a modifier -->
      <span class="heading-primary_text--sub">One Page Parallax</span>
    </h1>
```

In this way you can make the `sub` a modifier class for the subtext.

More info can be seen here https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#modifier

Hope  this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the right way. You cannot use block (or element) modifier alone on the HTML tag without specifying the block (or element) class itself.

Please refer to BEM documentation here: https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#modifier

> A modifier can't be used alone From the BEM perspective, a modifier
>   can't be used in isolation from the modified block or element. A
>   modifier should change the appearance, behavior, or state of the
>   entity, not replace it.

Here is a code example from the docs:

```
<!-- Correct. The `search-form` block has the `theme` modifier with the value `islands` -->
<form class="search-form search-form_theme_islands">
   <input class="search-form__input">
   <button class="search-form__button">Search</button>
</form>

<!-- Incorrect. The modified class `search-form` is missing -->
<form class="search-form_theme_islands">
   <input class="search-form__input">
   <button class="search-form__button">Search</button>
</form>
```

You mentioned that you don't need an element class, this topic is also covered in BEM docs
https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#why-include-the-block-name-in-modifier-and-element-names

semuzaboi's suggestion sounds as a good alternative to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a much simpler way to do this just using basic HTML. You only want to have one h1 per page and since you said that your second span of your h1 is a "subheading" I feel like you would be way better off marking that one as an h2 instead of two spans of different context within one h1 heading! Always good to use the built in benefits of HTML first if you can.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, elements are specified after two `__` like `block__element_modifier`.

Secondly, yes. Blocks may not have any elemenets inside, but rather have modifiers (most common case a block with lang modifiers for Internationalization (`block_lang_ru`))

PS as well as element may not have any modifiers inside. But block can not be nested inside another one. They should be placed inside one directory on the same level.

Comment: So you mean, Blocks can have just Modifiers without Elements, like i have main and sub modifiers inside Block without Elements?

Comment: @IrfanDayan Yes, you are right. The only thing I would mention is that sub and text are more likely to be the elements. Because modifiers are more about representation rather than filling